# Laravel request date validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner webdeveloper / php laravel developer.

I have this request:

```
class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $id = $this->route('product');

        return array_merge(
            [
                'name' => ['required', 'max:255', Rule::unique('products')->ignore($id)->whereNull('deleted_at')],
                'slug' => ['required', 'max:255', Rule::unique('products')->ignore($id)->whereNull('deleted_at')],
                'price' => ['required', 'numeric'],
                'preorder_release_date' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            ],
            $this->generateTranslationsRules()
        );
    }

    private function generateTranslationsRules(): array
    {
        $rules = [];

        foreach (LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLanguagesKeysExceptDefault() as $locale) {
            $rules[$locale . '.name'] = ['required', 'max:255'];
            $rules[$locale . '.slug'] = ['required', 'max:255'];
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

It's work fine.

I need to add a requirement for preorder_release_date - the date cannot be earlier than today. How can I write it down?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Laravel validation `before`

```php
 'preorder_release_date' => ['required','date','date_format:Y-m-d','before:today'],
```

> **NOTE** : date format you need to adjust based on your request

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-before